# rootViewController and addSubview in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

Im starting to learn OC.

The first question is about `_window.rootviewcontroller` and `[_window addSubview:...]`

Both of the two ways can set `view` for `UIWindow` (actually, `UIWindow` is inherited from `UIView`).

So what I want to know is :

Is setting the `rootviewcontroller` for `window` just using the `addSubview` method to implement , or it's something else?

more exactly:

is

```
_window.rootviewcontroller = viewController;
```

meaning

```
[_window addSubview: viewController.view];
```

or

```
_window = viewController.view; //UIWindow : UIView
```

or something else?

Thanks a lot.

Is there anyone who can tell me some details about UIWindow and the rootViewController property?

Comment: For this first you need to understand the difference between the UIView and UIViewController ....

Comment: Enjoy Cocoa, it's a fun framework. Welcome to SO too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `addSubview`: to have to pass a `UIView` instance but when you call `rootviewcontroller` you passing `UIViewController` instance to the `UIWindow`.

You can use `addSubview` but you have to associate `UIView` superview (Which needs to be `UIViewController`) to the `UIWindow`, to make it behave the same,
something like that (old way to to that:

```
[window addSubview:myViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

By using `rootviewcontroller` it will do it for you.

This is taken from Apple:

> The root view controller provides the content view of the window.
>   Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window. If the window has an existing view
>   hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are
>   installed.

Comment: I think it's different in implementation. Set root view controller is make the window view become a reference to the root view vontroller's view. While addSubview is to set a subview

Comment: exactly, I want to know the meaning(implementation) of the "content view". using 'addSubview' is also a way to get a "content view"

Comment: @youKnowDai addSubview adds a view to the end of the list of subviews and that's it. But rootViewController assign the view controller to it's property, add view controller's view as the content view of the window and remove views from the hierarchy if already exists.

Comment: I may Got it. Do You mean: window and rootviewcontroller's relationship is similar with the relationship between normal view and viewController.@Greg

Comment: I really made a bad question... sorry   :(   @Greg

Answer (score -2):

Obviously not. The root view controller is generally assigned to window in appdelegate class.
Also, root view controller is always associated with UINavigationController. So that any root view controller of a UINavigationController will be a its content view controller.

Where as, add subview is just a method of UIView class. Which helps to add any subview to the respective view.

Comment: @R_Developer, please correct this line, `Also, root view controller is always associated with UINavigationController`.. its not always, but may be and depend on requirements.

Comment: @Hemang, I didn't get you. If you can explain this more. May be that could add some more in my knowledge.

Comment: @R_Developer, Yes sure, a `rootViewController` can be a navigation controller or `tabBarController` or a normal `UIViewController`.